# How to convert yyyymmdd to dd-mm-yyyy in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column which contains dates in varchar2 with varying formats such as 19.02.2013, 29-03-2013, 30/12/2013 and so on. But the most annoying of all is 20130713 (which is July 13, 2013) and I want to convert this to dd-mm-yyyy or dd-mon-yyyy.

Comment: That should teach you to never store dates in VARCHAR columns.

Comment: In fact `yyyyMMdd` is in some ways a better format than the others, as it's naturally sorted... but yes, you should use the appropriate data type to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column contains all those various formats, you'll need to deal with each one.  Assuming that your question includes *all* known formats, then you have a couple of options.

You can use to_char/to_date.  This is dangerous because you'll get a SQL error if the source data is not a valid date (of course, getting an error might be preferable to presenting bad data).

Or you can simply rearrange the characters in the string based on the format.  This is a little simpler to implement, and doesn't care what the delimiters are.

Method 1:

```
   case when substr(tempdt,3,1)='.'
        then to_char(to_date(tempdt,'dd.mm.yyyy'),'dd-mm-yyyy')
        when substr(tempdt,3,1)='-'
        then tempdt
        when length(tempdt)=8
        then to_char(to_date(tempdt,'yyyymmdd'),'dd-mm-yyyy')
        when substr(tempdt,3,1)='/'
        then to_char(to_date(tempdt,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Method 2:

```
case when length(tempdt)=8
     then substr(tempdt,7,2) || '-' || substr(tempdt,5,2) || '-' || substr(tempdt,1,4)
     when length(tempdt)=10
     then substr(tempdt,1,2) || '-' || substr(tempdt,4,2) || '-' || substr(tempdt,7,4)
end
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a556b/8/0)

Comment: Thanks, method 2 helped me out with a similar issue!

Answer (score 11):

Convert to date, then format to char:

```
select to_char(to_date('20130713', 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd MON yyyy') from dual;
```

gives `13 JUL 2013`.

Answer (score 3):

The comments about datatypes while true, don't do much to help you with your current problem.  A combination of to_date and to_char might work.

```
update yourtable
set yourfield = to_char(to_date(yourfield, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
where length(yourfield) = 8
and yourfield not like '%-%'
and yourfield not like '%.%'
```